# How to check DND status of a mobile number in Android?

Tags: android

I have an application built that works for checking DND Status, it has an  edittext field and a button. In edittext the user enters a mobile number and on click of button I want to check the DND status of in android.  How to check DND status of a mobile number?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtHeading"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="12">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCheckCheckDND"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtNumber" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Check Status"    
/>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please elaborate on what you mean by "DND Status".

Comment: DND is Do not Disturb Service Provided by the TRAI that Stops Promotional and telemarketing Calls and SMS.

Answer (score 0):

For DND check you need a membership of [TRAI](http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/) http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/ then TRAI provide you all DND active database in CSV formate. 
Also you can use third part toll of http apis eg. http://checkdnd.com/api/check_dnd_no_api.php?mobiles=9999999999
[Free DND Check API](http://checkdnd.com)